# JavaScript: window.setTimeout(), force early expire

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a `<div>` on my page that refreshes automatically every two minutes with updated log entries.  When I first load my webpage, I call the following function.

```
function getLogs() {
    var filter = $('#filter').val();
    $.get("index-ajax.asp", { queryType: "getLogs", filter: filter, 
        uTime: new Date().getTime() },

        function(data){
            $("#logEntries").html(data);
            window.setTimeout("getLogs()",120000);
    });
}
```

I know the above code could be cleaner with `window.setInterval(...);` but I just like the control of `window.setTimeout(...);`.

My question, is it possible to cancel the next timeout execution?  In the event that I change the filter, I'd like to cancel the next timeout, and call the function right away, which would reschedule the timeout function.  Is there a better way to achieve that result?

Note that the above code is in jQuery.

Comment: Note: Do *NOT* pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`!  Pass functions. `window.setTimeout(getLogs, 120000);`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks for the tip on the strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

Ex:

```
var clr = window.setTimeout(getLogs,120000);
```

The when you wan to clear it:

```
clearTimeout(clr);
```

Comment: P.S. Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - correct, good catch. I wasn't even proofing the code. Updated.

Comment: There's a function `clearInterval` too, but you can use `clearTimeout` and it will work just as fine.

Answer (score 3):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) returns a `timerID` that you can pass to [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout):

```
// Note we are passing the *function* rather than a string
// Also note the lack of () - we are *not* calling the function
// setTimeout will do that for us
var timerID = setTimeout(getLogs, 120000);
// Fake condition - we cancel the timer if the timerID is even
if (timerID % 2 === 0) {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always define a new variable based on a filter value and if that filter value is set, use a while statement to omit the timeout:

```
if(filter == "whatevs"){
    var i=true;
}
function(data){
    $("#logEntries").html(data);
    while(i!=true){
        window.setTimeout("getLogs()",120000);
    }
}
```